# Is it possible to add fields to the table "account_emailaddress"?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want to add a new field to an existing table account_emailaddress (preserving this table), from allauth. But I can't figure out how to do it. Is it possible to customize the model?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new class with a 1:1 connection:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MoreData(models.Model):
    new_data = models.CharField("...", max_length=...)
    user = models.OneToOneField((User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

This way you can add data to a current model without touching it.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a possibility. But I would like to keep it unified so as not to multiply the models. It's not possible?

Comment: Check out this exceptional good tutorial, which covers almost every case: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html